# Pull out css value from collection of objects

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to take a collection of objects (checkboxes, in my case) and pluck just the css classes from them.

So far, I can get the collection of objects like this
    $(':checked')

If I call

`$(':checked').first().attr('class')`

it returns something like

```
"my-class"
```

I want do to this for the collection of objects, but all I am getting back is an empty array when I try something like this.

```
var classes = $(':checked').map(function(obj) {
  $(obj).attr('class')
})
```

Comment: You should `return`?

Comment: `return $(this).attr('class')`

Comment: Maybe you want `$(':checked').first().attr('class').split(' ')`

Comment: @Tushar - Original collection

Comment: Still give [ ] when using return

Comment: @RyanAsensio okay, add HTML, JS and jsfiddle demo with complete code and expected result

Comment: Yep I'm a noob, Lemme try and do that for you. Thanks!

Comment: @RyanAsensio Don't take it wrong, I just mean to add some explanation so that it'll be easier to understand code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return the value inside the **[`map()`](https://api.jquery.com/map/)** callback function and use **[`get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/)** or **[`toArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/toArray/)** for get result as an array.

**Update :** Also in callback function first parameter refers to the index not dom object. So you need to use either `this` or second parameter.

```
var classes = checked.map(function() {
  return $(this).attr('class');
  //-^--
}).get();
```

or

```
var classes = $(':checked').map(function(i,obj) {
  //                                   --^--
  return $(obj).attr('class')
}).get()
```

Comment: This still returns [ ] for the collection

Comment: Yep, the "this" was the problem. Thank you my friend.

Answer (score 0):

Make few changes in your `click` handler as shown below:

I have created a sample snippet for you.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".btn").click(function(){
      var checked = $(":checked");
      var classes = checked.map(function(obj) {
        return $(this).attr('class'); // refers to each checked element
      }).get(); // returns an array of the above map

    console.log(classes);  
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="class1" type="checkbox"/>

<input class="class2" type="checkbox"/>

<input class="btn" type="button" value="getchecked"/>
```